# hbm2java reverse engineering to use List and ArrayList instead of Set and HashSet

Tags: hibernate, eclipse-plugin, hibernate-tools

I use hbm2java plugin in Eclipse to generate the entity classes. The tool decides to use Set and HashSet for relationships between tables. 
What I want is to use List and ArrayList() instead. How easy to do that?

Comment: If you want a list returned in a hibernate one to many you need specify an element to hold the index. (otherwise there is no way for the order be persisted).

Comment: Thanks mate, can you elaborate more on "element to hold the index"? is that something in the DB to setup? I am using SQL Server and the reference columns are indexed already.

Comment: This is something you set up in the mapping.  If you use annotations it looks something like this: @Entity
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    @OrderColumn(name="order")
    private List<Child> children;
}